# How to allow password authentication OR key authentication on CentOS 5.7?

Tags: ssh, rsa, keys

is it possible to enable the use of password authentication or key authentication in CentOS 5.7? All I can find is setting PasswordAuthentication to no which forces the use of keys...

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to allow users to login with either password or key, not both?

Comment: Yes either, not both.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disabling `PasswordAuthentication` doesn't force keys, it disables password authentication, as advertised.

`PubkeyAuthentication` determines whether key authentication is allowed.

So, to answer your question directly, the following config allows either password or key auth:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean you want something like this:

```
Match User user1
    PasswordAuthentication no
    RSAAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes

Match User user2
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    RSAAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication no
```

Comment: Where put the content for ? Is it in `ssh_config`?

Comment: Place this configuration at the end of `ssh_config`

Comment: Is there a way to do this for root (user1), but the other config for "everyone else"? How does one write "everyone else" in place of user2?